# How can I execute an anonymous procedure via mybatis

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, mybatis

I use mybatis-3.2.4 and PostgreSQL. I try to execute a anonymous procedure but failed. The following is my demo sql:

```
<delete id = "deleteSomeTable" statementType = "CALLABLE">
    {call
        declare
        begin
            delete from test1;
            delete from test2;
        end
     }
</delete>
```

But when I execute this sql, a error occurs and error message is:

```
Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLExeception: 
    incorrect function or procedure escape program at 51
```

the 51th character is the first semicolon.

How can I fix this problem? Or anyone show me a demo to execute an anonymous procedure via mybatis?

Comment: It's very likely that you can't, or you'd have to use native SQL for it at least. Remember that PostgreSQL doesn't allow PL/PgSQL inline, you need a `DO` block or an explicit function.

Comment: What's the larger context for why you want/need an anonymous procedure?

Comment: @CraigRinger I use a DO block and it works, thanks a lot!

Comment: @khampson I don't want to store a procedure in my db, so I embed a anonymous procedure in my java program.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you only have to write the declare statement like this

```
declare
    begin
        delete from test1;
        delete from test2;
    end
```